# Deploy django-channels with Apache2 and Daphne

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm trying to learn to use `django-channels` and have worked through both the tutorial and [this multichat example](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat).  I am now trying to deploy it on a Digital Ocean droplet using Apache and Daphne.  I would happily use Daphne by itself but I do not understand how to.

So this is my Apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.co.uk
    ServerName multichat.mysite.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.multichat.mysite.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/multichat
    WSGIDaemonProcess multichat python-path=/var/www/multichat python-home=/var/www/multichat/env
    WSGIProcessGroup multichat
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/multichat/multichat/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/multichat/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/multichat/static/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /var/www/multichat/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/multichat/static/

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/multichat/multichat/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/multichat>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I've installed Redis and have it up and running.

I've included this file in `/etc/systemd/system/daphne.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon for multichat
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/multichat/multichat
ExecStart=/var/www/multichat/env/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 multichat.asgi:application

# Not sure if should use 'on-failure' or 'always'. 
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Although the webpage comes up and I can login etc, when it comes to a chatroom I have the following error in console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://multichat.mysite.co.uk/chat/stream/'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404

I'm clearly not setting up something correctly but I don't know where to turn.  I would happily scrape Apache if I can get a pointer on how to use just Daphne, but I've tried and got nowhere with that either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Apache to run ASGI in Django Channels? Is Apache even required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098504/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-asgi-in-django-channels-is-apache-even-required)

Comment: Henry, can you add apache code that works for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've configured Apache to serve Django content using WSGI protocol, but WSGI doesn't support web sockets. That is why Daphne is here. It doesn't use WSGI to serve Django content, so you can use it with web sockets.

To use Daphne instead, you should remove WSGI settings from apache file and put `ProxyPass` instead, which should point to your daphne server. The proper line should look like this:

```
<Location />
   ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8001/     
</Location>
```

As your daphne server is running on the same server, but on port 8001.

Comment: I remove the WSGI but I now get an Internal Server Error, the message being "No protocol handler was valid for the IRL /chat/stream/ (scheme 'http'). If you are using a DSO verion of mod-proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using Loadmodule"

Comment: I've run `a2enmod proxy_http` which sorted the above but now I have "attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8001 (127.0.0.1) failed" "failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1"  Does that mean Daphne isn't running correctly?

Comment: So if I run `daphne multichat.asgi:application --port 8001 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2` from the terminal I can get the site up but none of the static files are loading and the chat functionality isn't there

Comment: *remove WSGI settings* means removing `WSGIScriptAlias`, `directory for wsgi.py` and everything, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8001/
</Location>

#And load the next modules in the main file config:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

#remove WSGI settings
```